# How do I use time machine to access system files like /etc/hosts?

Tags: time-machine

Time Machine makes it easy to recover older versions of your personal users files; How do you restore an older version of a system file (such as `/etc/hosts`) using Time Machine?

Answer (score 6):

For OS X 10.11, El Capitan, the steps are:

1. Open **Applications > Time Machine**; or use the Time Machine menu bar item and select **Enter Time Machine**.
2. Reveal the **Go to Folder** sheet within Time Machine using the key combination: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
3. Within the **Go to Folder** sheet enter the path `/private/etc` and select **Go**.
4. You can now browse your back-ups of `/etc/` and restore files as needed.

Answer (score 3):

I just used Time Machine on Yosemite to recover `/usr/bin/unzip`; this is how I did it, given that my Time Machine backup disk is named `Backup` and my machine is named `MyMacBook` (not really):

1. Set Finder to show all OS files: From a command line, run `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`
2. Open a Finder window to your backup media (eg: `Devices / Backup` ) and then drill down into the latest appropriate backup. The `Backups.backupdb/MyMacBook` directory will have a series of directories named as timestamps (`YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS`) and `Latest`. Each of these directories represents a Time Machine backup.

   On my MacBook, the correct directory was `Backups.backupdb/MyMacBook/2015-10-22-130134/Macintosh HD/usr/bin`.
3. Open another Finder window, then use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to go to your system folder (`/usr/bin` in my case).
4. Drag and copy the file (`unzip` in my case) from the Time Machine window to the system window. You will probably be prompted for your password if it's a system file.

You can do this from the command line:

```
sudo cp -p /Volumes/Backup/Backups.backupdb/MyMacBook/2015-10-22-130134/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/unzip /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that may be the only thing OS X recovers via Time Machine, especially in El Capitan, with its infamous System Integrity Protection (SIP).

*If all you wish to be able to recover other than your user files* is `/etc/hosts`, then set a root cronjob (or I guess I should say a `launchd` job) to `scp` or `rsync` the file somewhere else.

***Note:*** `crontab` is supposedly "deprecated" in later versions of OS X in favor of `launchd`, but **it still works** (and IMHO, is way easier to setup than a scheduled task via `launchd` -- especially if you have a previous Linux/Unix background).

Otherwise, if you wish to recover the entire filesystem, you should look into alternative backup solutions such as [CrashPlan](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/), which is quite cheap, and pretty much the standard cloud backup solution these days.

Comment: Time Machine does back up the entire system, at least up through Yosemite.

Comment: That's what I'm saying though -- I'm not sure El Capitan supports full system backups because of the new System Integrity Protection, which is pretty much supposed to prevent anything from being changed outside of /Users.  This is something I/you/we/OP should do some further research on, because SIP was really a game-changer for a lot of things in OS X and changed the functionality of a lot of things.  I imagine whether it is turned on or off could possibly make a big difference for Time Machine backups in El Capitan.  I guess it would help to know what version of OS X OP is running.

Comment: I won't find out until my company moves beyond Yosemite; ask me again in 6 months.